# How can i modify a matrix using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I'm trying to modify a matrix ( multiplying each value by 2 ) using pointers but my code isn't working. I've seen some examples where the function `malloc` was being used, i'm not sure how would it be necessary in my code though.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void changematrix(int **mm,int row, int column)
{
    int i,j;
    for( i = 0;i < row; i++)
    {
        for( j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            *(*(mm + i) + j) = 2* *(*(mm + i) + j);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int row, column;
    printf("Type the number of row\n");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    printf("Type the number of columns\n");
    scanf("%d",&column);
    int mat[row][column];
    printf("Now type the numbers\n");
for( i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for( j = 0; j < column; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
    }
}


    changematrix(&mat,row,column);


    for( i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for( j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: If your compiler is not emitting warnings about mismatched types, then either turn up the warning level or get a better compiler.  Your function parameter `mm`, of type `int **`, does not have the correct type to match the argument expression `mat`, of type `int[row][column]`.

Comment: By not using *those* pointers. A `int**` is not synonymous with `int[n][m]`. One is a pointer to pointer, the other an array of arrays.

Comment: Am I the only one who's itching to ditch the nested `for()` loops and just utilize the fact that `int[m][n]` is a **contiguous** memory chunk thus reducing looping to just one, non-nested loop?

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/CV3leD)

Comment: @YePhIcK: I hope so. The additions/dereferencing is awful; that's what the index-operator is for. However, the loops are correct. Leave optimisations to the compiler, concentrate on readable code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
void changematrix(int row, int column, int (*mm)[column])
{
    int i,j;
    for( i = 0;i < row; i++)
    {
        for( j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            mm[i][j] = 2* mm[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Function call should be like this:

```
changematrix(row, column, mat);
```

Comment: @VitorMatos; I edited my answer, is it ok now? :) (`mm` is a pointer to an array of `column` `int`s)

Comment: If you want to use an `int**` instead, you'll need to create an array of pointers, which you don't currently have in your code.

Comment: @VitorMatos, the revision to this answer makes it clear that it *is* using pointers.  It is semantically identical to the original form, however -- i.e. the original was using a pointer, too.

Answer (score 0):

This would leave s and l pointing to elements of the array arr. If you just wanted the values of integers then the alternative would be to define int variables in main() and pass their addresses to func()...

```
void func(int arr[], int** s, int** l, int n){
    /* snip */

    *l = &arr[n-1];
    *s = &arr[0];
}

func(arr, &s, &l, size);
```

Comment: Man, this is gona be little off topic, but I want to give small tip: you see, you have got void function and have 2 pointer results, which performs memory access. You can create struct with both values and return it (note you can return max 2 entries, each max size of register). I mean something like `struct Ret {int* s, l;} Ret func(int* arr, int n) {.. return (Ret) {.l = ... , .s = ...}}`. Instead of memory access you return results in registers.